# ORA 00904 invalid identifier with left/right outer join

Tags: oracle, join, oracle11g, partitioning, outer-join

I have query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.id=table2.c_id
```

It gives me an error

> ORA-00904 "table2.c_id" invalid identifier

The thing is that query works with FULL OUTER JOIN  and with INNER JOIN - no error. Even this one works:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.id=table2.c_id(+)
```

Error only occurs with right or left outer join and only on test db.

Both tables are partitioning.

Production db, where query runs perfect - Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

Test db, where query fails - Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Configuration of tables on both db are the same.

Any suggestions what could it be?

Comment: I don't have your tables to test. Please post the create table and insert statements for sample data. Or else, create a SQL Fiddle and post a link

Comment: Have you tried using aliases for table1 and table2, i.e. `select * from table1 t1 left outer join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.c_id` ? Is there a database link involved? (Oracle has a long history of broken ANSI Joins when DB links are involved)

Comment: @FrankSchmitt yes, I used aliases - no success. Not sure about db links, will check

Comment: Some more things to check (all related to Oracle bugs with ANSI syntax):  
- does one of the tables contain a domain index? 
- does one of the tables contain a CLOB/BLOB column?
- does one of the tables contain a XMLTYPE column?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with the SQL.

On my **12c** database, no issues:

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL> create table x(id number);

Table created.

SQL> create table y(c_id number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into x values(1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into y values(1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into y values(2);

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM y LEFT OUTER JOIN x
  3  ON x.id=y.c_id;

      C_ID         ID
---------- ----------
         1          1
         2
```

On **11g R2**, see this [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1b877a/2).

Comment: Of course it should/t be any issue, it's simple outer join which MUST works... that's why I am asking if someone know what is wrong. May be it is some partitioning tables issue...

Comment: @Tatiana That's why I asked you to provide the tables and sample data. You just gave a simple query saying it's not working.

Comment: I understand it, but I can't put here code from our company db... I will try to provide some scripts (with another names of columns and so on)

Answer (score -1):

could you try this

```
 SELECT table1.* ,table2.*
 FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
 ON table1.id=table2.c_id
```